# Replace line in text file with user input at terminal

Tags: awk, user-input

I am trying to prompt the user for two pieces of information:

1) The line number in the file to be changed
2) The value to change it to.

My script so far:

```
echo "Do you wish to enter a variable to be changed?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
  case $yn in
    Yes)
      echo "Please enter a variable to be changed"
      read lineNum
      echo "Please enter variable's new value"
      read val
      awk -v lineNum="$lineNum" -v val="$val" \
       'BEGIN { if (NR == lineNum) print val; else print $0}' \
        test.in > newtest.in
      ;;
    No)
      break;;
  esac
done
```

The test.in has numeric values all in one column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Thanks.

***EDIT***
Forgot to mention the error :D. For some reason, the a new file is created but only with the new val that was specified, I imagine this might have something to do with using $0, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: just remove `BEGIN` for `awk` there, and change if statement to `if (NR == lineNum) {print val;} else {print $0}`, or better `print (NR==lineNum)?val:$0`

Comment: Wow... Thanks! Can you explain what happened? Feel free to post this as the answer and I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: A couple of hints for your UI: use `read -p "prompt: " varname` instead of `echo "prompt"; read varname`; for `select`, use `PS3="select prompt: "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `awk` [the **BEGIN** block/rule is executing before the first input record is read and only once](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html#Using-BEGIN_002fEND), for your script and awk to work you need to remove it since that's not required here, then `awk` will execute that block for every input/record reads.

Also personally I use *Ternary* condition when I only have one action/else statement.

```
awk '{ print (NR==lineNum)?val:$0 }'
```